# Unable to install appium 1.6.0-beta3 using npm as error(refer to attached screenshot) arises

Tags: macos, appium

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL4Ba.png)Details:
Xcode version 8.0 Mac OS sierra 10.12

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the npm command with sudo before? In my windows machine I had same problem with 1.6.0-beta2. But when I executed using elevated login it worked. If this is mac I would suggest using avm.

I will try the same with AVM on my mac later today and I will update you if I see same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with Brew.

Run these commands at the terminal one after one:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install node

npm install -g appium
```

(Running this will install the latest stable version, but if you want to install a specific verstion then run e.g. `npm install -g appium@1.4.16`)

Hope it helps :)